# How to encrypt and decrypt nvarchar(max) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I need to encrypt column `nvarchar(max)` and when I write select query automatically decrypt column value, something like always encrypted in SQL Server 2016.

SQL Server always encrypted does not support `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

NVARCHAR(MAX) is supported for *Always encrypted*. Below datatypes are not supported.

[Always encrypted MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Columns using one of the following data types: xml,
>   timestamp/rowversion, image, ntext, text, sql_variant, hierarchyid,
>   geography, geometry, alias, user defined-types.

For encryption of the data, you have got multiple options:

- [Sql server encryption using keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-and-database-encryption-keys-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - Here, you have to decrypt the values when you read the data

```sql
select empid , SSN , SSNEncrypted , 
convert(varchar,DECRYPTBYKEY(SSNEncrypted) ) 
[Decrypted SSN] from employees  WHERE EMPID = 1
```

- [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15) : Here, the data is encrypted at rest. When you read the data, decryption is happening on the fly.

```sql
select empid , SSN from employees  WHERE EMPID = 1 -- Here, SSN is decrypted on the fly. transparent to user
```

- [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - Encryption is taken care by the application driver

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT empid , SSN from employees WHERE EMPID = 1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```